# Items get forgotten by crafting logistics pipes when the world is reloaded

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

I'm playing *Minecraft* with the *Technic Pack* and using *Logistics Pipes*, especially *Crafting Logistics Pipes*, to automatically process items in machines, e.g. smelt items in a furnace.

The logistics pipes have the property that they "forget" requests when the world is saved and loaded again. When a request is fulfilled by a crafting logistics pipe, an item is put into a furnace to smelt and the smelting will take some time. When I save and reload the world during that time, the item, or it's product, will still be in the furnace, but the associated request does not exist anymore. So the item will stay in the furnace.

When I request another item from the same crafting logistics pipe, the pipe will instantly pull the already smelted item out of the furnace but another one of the item needed to produce the requested one will be routed to the furnace. So from then on, there will always be one item too many inside the furnace.

This problem also happens with *Automatic Crafting Pipes*, where necessary items may arrive at different times and there is a time frame where reloading the world would get some of the items "lost".

There are also other reasons for this to happen. E.g. if a request can't be completed because of some other problem in the network, but the Logistics Pipes network thinks it can. So enhancing the Crafting Logistics Pipes implementation to save and restore active requests would not completely prevent this from happening and a more robust solution that I can implement with items from the Technic Pack is desired.

Is there any way solve this problem?

Comment: I was thinking about attaching a _Provider Logistics Pipe_ to the furnaces in question but I fear such a pipe could "steal" an item that has been produced for a _Crafting Logistics Pipe_ still waiting for it. Is that a valid concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach a logistic chassis with an extractor module (either mark 1 or 2) to the side of the furnace it will extract any excess products from the furnace and send them to the default route, do not worry about the extractor module taking items that the crafting pipe was waiting for as it has a lower priority so will not take the items unless no other pipe wants it.

Comment: Should this also work for additional items put on an _Automatic Crafting Table_? These items do not appear in the output slot but remain in the crafting area.

Comment: @Feuermurmel What do you mean _standard_ logistic pipes? Extractor modules are part of the same mod as crafting logistic pipes.